# Properly handling NSURLConnection errors

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, network-programming

I have a simple form interface set up that send username and password information to a server: (working)

```
    NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@&pass=%@",[self urlEncodeValue:sysUsername],[self urlEncodeValue:password]];
NSLog(@"Post data -> %@", postData);
///
NSData* postVariables = [postData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString* postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postVariables length]];
NSURL* postUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/~csmith/cocoa/test.php"];
[request setURL:postUrl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: postVariables];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
NSLog(@"Post data SENT & returned -> %@", returnData);
```

How do I handle connection errors such as no internet connection, firewall, etc.
Also, does this method use the system-wide proxy settings? Many of my users are behind a proxy.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use synchronous requests, use asynchronous request instead and indicate activity using [indeterminate progress indicators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ProgIndic/Tasks/IndeterProgIndic.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000113-CJCBJJJJ).

When using asynchronous requests, you have to set a delegate implement [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-DontLinkElementID_17), notably:

- [`-connectionDidFinishLoading:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJHIAJA)
- [`-connection:didFailWithError:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJGFGCF)

From the docs:

> Unless a NSURLConnection receives a cancel  message, the delegate will receive one and only one of `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, or `connection:didFailWithError:`  message, but never both. In addition, once either of messages are sent, the delegate will receive no further messages for the given NSURLConnection.

As for the last question:

> Also, does this method use the system-wide proxy settings?

Yes, `NSURLConnection` uses them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should use asynchronous request to handle proxy and network errors. This is more efficient.
To add extra check you can add reach-ability test in your code before communications. you can find reach-ability test code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995822/check-internet-connection-in-cocoa-application)