# Network notification to a daemon

Tags: objective-c, macos, daemon

I'd like to create a daemon which makes a series of requests to a webserver every time the machine comes online. I could use the SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags function in a loop to figure out if a connection is present -- however I'm considering other alternatives. Would it be possible to have launchd notify my daemon of some event that corresponds to the machine being connected to the network?

Could you point me towards reading resources for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You should use SCNetworkReachability, but in somewhat other way. Just create reachability object, add it to run loop and do whatever you want in callback. See answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627058/how-to-determine-internet-connection-in-cocoa) related question