# Is there an API on mac-osX to check if network is available?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

How can I programmatically determine whether network is available on mac os or not?

Comment: **Take a look at these**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627058/how-to-determine-internet-connection-in-cocoa

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995822/check-internet-connection-in-cocoa-application

Comment: There is no Mac that has no network hardware. So, do you mean "any network interface on", "WiFi connected", "LAN router reachable", or "some server on the internet reachable"? There are many ways to have or not to have network available.

Comment: try the reachabilty framework from apple

Comment: Reachability framework helped . THanks