# sample code to ping an IP address in objective-c(Xcode)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, ping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a simple Ping method in Cocoa/Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798454/how-to-write-a-simple-ping-method-in-cocoa-objective-c)
>   [check internet connection in cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995822/check-internet-connection-in-cocoa-application)

I want to ping an IPaddress and know whether it is currently in network or not.I am developing iPad/Iphone application in Xcode(objective-C).Please help me with sample code as I am new to this technology.

```
         I don't want to download other application to ping IPaddress.
```

Sushma

Comment: Can anyone help me with the sample code

Comment: In what way do you need help?

Comment: I am getting errors when using the samples given on net.Share me the code if you have implemented already