# Check if a socket is connected in mac os x

Tags: c++, macos, sockets

In Windows platform I can check if a socket is connected by this code:

```
bool isConnected(int socket)
{
    int err;
    int len = sizeof (err);
    getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*)&err, &len);
    return err == 0;
}
```

In OS X this function always returns true.
What is the official way to do it?

Comment: Try Reachability : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995822/check-internet-connection-in-cocoa-application

Comment: It is necessary for me to use std socket functions, I can not use SCNetwork for some reasons.

Answer (score 2):

This function works for both Windows and Mac platforms:

```
bool isConnected(int socket)
{
    int err;
    #ifdef __APPLE__
    uint32_t len;
    #elif _Windows
    int len;
    #endif
    sockaddr_in addr;
    len = sizeof (addr);
    err = getpeername(socket, (sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
    return err == 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. `getpeername()` can returned cached info after a disconnect before the socket handle is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to determine if a blocking socket is connected is to perform an actual send/recv operation and check the result for error.  On Windows, a non-blocking socket can also issue asynchronous notifications on socket activity, like `FD_CLOSE` for disconnects.

The one place `SOL_ERROR` comes in handy is for a non-blocking `connect()` call. After `select()` reports the connect operation is finished, `SOL_ERROR` can be used to determine whether `connect()` was successful or why it failed.

Comment: Please see my answer and say your opinion about it.

Answer (score 0):

This - `if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa) < 0)`  is close enough to  winsock's `isConnected`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main() {
  register int s;
  register int bytes;
  struct sockaddr_in sa;
  char buffer[BUFSIZ+1];

  if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("socket");
    return 1;
  }

  bzero(&sa, sizeof sa);

  sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sa.sin_port = htons(13);
  sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl((((((192 << 8) | 43) << 8) | 244) << 8) | 18);
  if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa) < 0) {
    perror("connect");
    close(s);
    return 2;
  }

  while ((bytes = read(s, buffer, BUFSIZ)) > 0)
    write(1, buffer, bytes);

  close(s);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer and say your opinion about it.